# 'int' object not callable error

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

I'm trying to create a program for school that outputs a drawn graph after entering it a mathematical expression, using SimpleGraphics, but I keep on getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bphip\Documents\Python Code Files\Assignment2rough.py", line 64, in <module>
    ellipse((x(x+30)+300),(y(x-30)+300),10,10)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
from SimpleGraphics import *

background("white")

setOutline("black")
setFill("black")
rect(0,300,800,1)
rect(400,0,1,600)

count=-15
numX=-13
numY=10
while count <=815:
    setFill("black")
    rect(count-5,297,1,8)
    rect(398,count-15,8,1)
    count=count+30
    setFont("Times",7)
    text(count-5,310,numX)
    text(410,count-15,numY)
    numX=numX+1
    numY=numY-1

from math import *

count_curve=0

expression=input("Enter a mathematical expression: ")

for x in range(-100,900):
    result=eval(expression)
    count_curve=count_curve+1
    remainder=count_curve%3
    if remainder==0:
        setOutline("red")
        setFill("red")
    elif remainder==1:
        setOutline("green")
        setFill("green")
    else:
        setOutline("blue")
        setFill("blue")
64    ellipse((x(x+30)+300),(y(x-30)+300),10,10)
```

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this error. Would anyone be able to explain it to me? I've numbered which line is giving me the error.

Comment: Replace `ellipse((x(x+30)+300),(y(x-30)+300),10,10)` with `ellipse((x*(x+30)+300),(y*(x-30)+300),10,10)`

Comment: Don't do this: `eval(expression)`...

Comment: In : ellipse((x(x+30)+300),(y(x-30)+300),10,10),

x(x+30) is not a valid expression. Please check and make necessary changes. Likewise y(x-30). It should be x*(x+30) and y*(x-30)